# password_hash seems to return a random variable

Tags: php, mysql, database, passwords, bcrypt

I am attempting to hash a password before I store it in a user database, so I run the code:

```
$hashedPass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

This code gives me a value, say $2y$10$wAJr0Z1spRtOcK4cLhIkguUCKgwZKYrwm.nRhm6AtCfDH8ri7ylJu which are stored in the database.
Now when I attempt to log in, the same string put in as a password gives a completely different $hashedPass: say $2y$10$cayCQDSQ6pCICSozuIgBNu9uIopIoT5R6Y7aHXG6wx4v/oKx.Ipse

Is this just random?  Is there something I should use instead?

Comment: `password_verify`.

Comment: only for completeness the link to [passoword_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php): http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: The results and how to use it is stated in the return value of the manual for the function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-returnvalues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. `password_hash` generates a salt which is used along with the plaintext password to generate a hash. The salt is generated randomly so the output will be different each time you call `password_hash`.

Use `password_verify` to verify passwords.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

All of the information necessary for `password_verify` to verify a plaintext password is contained in the hash itself. The anatomy of a hash depends on the algorithm used, for the password hash you provided:

```
$2y$10$wAJr0Z1spRtOcK4cLhIkguUCKgwZKYrwm.nRhm6AtCfDH8ri7ylJu
```

- **$2y$** This prefix indicates that this is a bcrypt hash
- **10** This is the cost parameter
- **wAJr0Z1spRtOcK4cLhIkgu** The first 22 character is the salt
- **UCKgwZKYrwm.nRhm6AtCfDH8ri7ylJu** The remaining 31 characters is the hash

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt

Comment: Note for completeness: The random salt plus some other data is prefixed to the hashed data so that `password_verify` can generate the same hash for comparison.

Comment: Can I run password_verify with both params as hashed passwords?  In the example on php.net, only one of the passwords is hashed

Comment: Oh wait. . .I just figured out that there is no reason to hash the password if it isn't saved.  Sorry